# Error using command-output to variable in bash functions using awk

Tags: linux, bash, function, awk, syntax-error

I'm getting an error trying to write the output of a command into a variable, which is defined in a function.

```
chk()
        hostsum=$(md5sum /etc/hosts | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
chk
```

It tells me about a syntax error:

> ./testchk.sh: Zeile 3: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort
>   `hostsum=$(md5sum /etc/hosts | awk -F" " '{print $1}')' ./testchk.sh:
>   Zeile 3:`    hostsum=$(md5sum /etc/hosts | awk -F" " '{print $1}')'

It works outer the function, but just won't because of the function adding some extra quotes.
Any ideas except using it out of the function?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question?  You need brackets (either {} or ()) on the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add braces:

```
chk() { hostsum=$(md5sum /etc/hosts | awk -F" " '{print $1}') ; }
```

Works fine for me here.  The [`bash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says that a function has to contain a compound command, of which  { *list* ; } is one example.

Comment: okay. this worked. thanks. but its strange, since every other function worked without the {}.

Comment: Did your other functions have one of the other compound command formats?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
chk() {
        hostsum=$(md5sum /etc/hosts | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
}
chk
```